# how to get all fields in a object.filter() django

Tags: django, object, filter, models

I am trying to get all fields to display but im only getting a few of my fields. I am unsure why so here is my views

my view imports

```
def switchingowners(request):
ownersofcar = Owner.objects.filter(CarID = request.user['CarID'])
for owner in ownersofcar :
            addingOwner = models.Owner(CarID=form['CarID'],Owner_Date=ownerofcar['Owner_Date']
                )
```

ok my models look like

```
class Owner(models.Model):

carID = models.ForeignKey(Car)    
Owner_Entry_Number = models.IntegerField()
Owner_Date = models.DateField('Proprietor start date', null=True, blank=True)

Owner_Last_Name = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
Owner_First_Name = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
Owner_Middle_Initial = models.CharField(max_length=6, null=True, blank=True)
Owner_Address = models.CharField(max_length=80, null=True, blank=True)
```

my database backend has information in all fields

```
ownersofcar = Owner.objects.filter(CarID = request.user['CarID'])
```

it tells me TypeError
and the filtered objects i see  are

```
self    

[<Owner: 1248612 MALCOLM  DESRIVIERES >, <Owner: 1248612  JULIETTA  REMY >, <Owner: 1248B612 THERESA  DESIR >, <Owner: 1248B612 ALEXANDER JEAN>]
```

where on earth are the other fields? i dont see any documentation on secifying which fields i want to receive cause i want them all!

each field has important information 
im basically switching all the names from one car to another car/ multiple cars

but filter is not giving back all the fields

Comment: The other fields are there, why do you think they aren't? You can access them like any other attribute.

Comment: You should, however, *show the code* that is giving a TypeError.

Comment: That's only the *string representation*. If you want to see all the fields in it just override the `__str__` method and return which representation you want.

Comment: its telling me typeerror and specifying the field that its looking for!
and it prints the fields that came with the queryset  and the are a few fields missing

Comment: i also did a logger.error(ownerofcar)
and its still not showing me all the fields

Comment: ok my str()method was causing the disappearance of fields sorry i am total noob at django

but now i try to access the filtered object
ownerofcar.Owner_Address 
i get this 
 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'Owner_Address'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are getting a type error because you are doing `request.user['CarId']`. Unless you using a custom user class this is not valid.

The fields are all there, what you see is just a string representation of your result as defined by the `__str__` or `__unicode__` method of `Owner`.

Either change this method or print the field that you want, e.g.:

```
for owner in ownersofcar:
    logger.error(owner.Owner_Address)
```

Comment: yea when i do that i get 
'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'Owner_Address'

Comment: Then you have a QuerySet, not a single object. Simply speaking, a QuerySet is a list of objects, which doesn't have the attribute. I suggest having a look at the Django documentation on making queries: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/queries/

Answer (score 0):

thanks to one of your guys suggestion i realize the error while fields were missing my coworker overrided the *str*() method and wasnt paying attention to that 
and the override is doign exactly what it needs to. not include the other fields

thanks guys

Comment: In addition to what Daniel said about the TypeError, you still seem to be missing the point the others are making. The fields are all there. The str representation is just that, a user defined representation of the model. The representation is not the model. The fields are there and accessible - if you do, using your code example, and ownersofcar is the queryset, you'll see that, e.g. ownersofcar[0].Owner_Last_Name will give you that field.